# Creating New Column Using IF and Apply Function

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, apply

My Age data is float and I want to create a new categorical column with three values: Elder, Child and Adult. I defined a function and added `iloc[0]` to iterate individual values in existing df['Age'] column. However, my result always 'Elder' with one unique result.

```
def ages(a):          
   if ((df['Age'].iloc[0])>50):  
      return 'Elder'  
   elif ((df['Age'].iloc[0])<12):  
      return 'Child'  
   elif (df['Age'].iloc[0]<50) & (df['Age'].iloc[0]>12):  
      return 'Adult'  
   df['Agem']=df['Age'].apply(ages)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I solved my loop problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parameter `axis=1` in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for working in function with scalars - processes by values:

```
def ages(a): 
    if (a > 50): 
        return 'Elder' 
    elif (a < 12): 
        return 'Child' 
    else: 
        return 'Adult' 

df['Agem']=df['Age'].apply(ages)
```

Faster solution with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['Age'] > 50
m2 = df['Age'] < 12

df['Agem']= np.select([m1, m2], ['Elder','Child'], default='Adult')
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=1000), columns=['Age'])
#print (df)

def ages(a): 
    if (a > 50): 
        return 'Elder' 
    elif (a < 12): 
        return 'Child' 
    else: 
        return 'Adult' 

df['Agem']=df['Age'].apply(ages)

m1 = df['Age'] > 50
m2 = df['Age'] < 12

df['Agem1']= np.select([m1, m2], ['Elder','Child'], default='Adult')
#print (df)

In [157]: %timeit df['Agem']=df['Age'].apply(ages)
577 µs ± 37.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [158]: %timeit df['Agem1']= np.select([m1, m2], ['Elder','Child'], default='Adult')
244 µs ± 1.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. You saved me a lot. Could you give me example for "....working in function with scalars - processes by values". Do you mean in the function above, we put categorical('Elder', 'Child'), and if we would put integer or float, we should put apply(function name, axis=1)?

Answer (score 0):

#### Correct use of `pd.Series.apply`

[`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) feeds each **value** in a series through a function. So there's no need to use `iloc` within your function:

```
def ages(a):          
    if a > 50:  
        return 'Elder'  
    elif a < 12:
        return 'Child'  
    else:
        return 'Adult'  

df['Agem'] = df['Age'].apply(ages)
```

#### Use `pd.cut` instead

More efficiently, you can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) to "bin" your ages into categories. The benefit here is your resultant series will have `Categorical` dtype, which has efficiency / memory benefits.

```
df['Agem'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=[0, 12, 50, np.inf],
                    labels=['Child', 'Adult', 'Elder'])

print(df)

   Age   Agem
0   10  Child
1   15  Adult
2   20  Adult
3   35  Adult
4   45  Adult
5   50  Adult
6   70  Elder

print(df.dtypes)

Age        int64
Agem    category
dtype: object
```